# Permission error when calling DoDirectPayment - PayPal

Tags: php, paypal

I am attempting to use PayPal's DoDirectPayment API call, we have bought PayPal Pro and created a sandbox account for testing. I am passing the following to the call (using our sandbox authentication):

```
array(
        "USERNAME"      => "OUR USERNAME",
        "PWD"           => "OUR PASSWORD",
        "SIGNATURE"     => "OUR SIGNATURE",
        "METHOD"        => "DoDirectPayment",
        "PAYMENTACTION" => "SALE",
        "CURRENCYCODE"  => "GBP"
        "METHOD"        => "DoDirectPayment",
        "IPADDRESS"     => $_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR'],
        "AMT"           => "10.00",
        "DESC"          => "Desc"
        ...
```

Amongst the other key/value pairs for the debit card information.

After submitting I get the following result.

```
    TIMESTAMP=2015-0713T10:06:57Z
    &CORRELATIONID=845382b8571ae
    &ACK=Failure
    &VERSION=0.000000
    &BUILD=17370573
    &L_ERRORCODE0=10002
    &L_SHORTMESSAGE0=Authentication/Authorization Failed
    &L_LONGMESSAGE0=You do not have permissions to make this API call
    &L_SEVERITYCODE0=Error
```

Other people have spoken about this error but they all seem to be for different things. Is there a setting somewhere that needs to be enabled for DoDirectPayment I can't seem to find it anywhere if so, or am I maybe missing some info that needs to be passed to PayPal?

Any help is greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Reset your paypal credentials, make sure you are using the correct ones for sandbox and live. You also have METHOD twice. If your current paypal test buyer and facilitator default currency is US create a new facilitator and set to GBP :)

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I have done all of the above but to no avail :( Going to get in touch with PayPal maybe they haven't upgraded us to Pro properly yet or something...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using the Sandbox credentials and getting this error, it is usually that you just need to upgrade your Sandbox seller account to Pro. When you go into your Sandbox and click on the seller email, in the profile you will see an option to upgrade to Pro and that will resolve the error.

Comment: I forgot I asked this question, thank you for your response this was the solution to the issue! :)